# jQuery plugin validationEngine's hook not executing

Tags: jquery, validation, hook

I'm trying to use [validationEngine's hooks](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introducing-hooks-in-the-jquery-form-validation-engine-plugin/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+position-absolute%2FnyJv+%28Position+Absolute+News+and+Articles%29) but can't get it working.

From reading the manual, the following code should show an alert box after blurring every field that does not validate... but the alert box is not showing...

```
$('#myform').validationEngine();

$('#myform').bind('jqv.field.result', function(event, field, errorFound, prompText) {
    alert('foo');
});
```

Note that the *normal* validation works great, so jQuery and validationEngine work fine.

Comment: I've proposed a fix:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/84

Comment: Update: Bug has been accepted by creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax queries handle incorrectly with trigger custom event. there is  a patch https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/pull/170

Answer (score 0):

Bug has been accepted by creator: http://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/84